# css custom font doesn't work

Tags: css, font-face

this is the beginning of my css

```
@charset "utf-8";

@font-face {
    font-family: 'dax';
    src: url('font/Dax.eot');
src: url('font/Dax.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
     url('font/Dax.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('font/dax-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), 
             url('font/Dax.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: 300;
}

html, body {
font-family: "dax", Arial, serif;
....
```

this is my font file and this is the hierarchy of my site folder
root contains: 
  index.html and 
  font and
  ....

font contains this: [screen](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/26009685/screen.png)

Comment: doasn't work. it just switches from arial to times new roman

Comment: Is your css file in the same folder as the html file ?

Comment: omg dumb me... I changed it this morning and i forgot to change that link as well. THX!!!!

Answer (score 1):

try it url('/font/dax-regular.ttf')